# The nohup process isn't listed using `ps`

Tags: linux, ssh, ps, nohup

**nohup** can help user keeping process running after log-out.

But while I log out & in again, the process `python` is gone.

#### Before log out

[image: console screenshot before]

#### Log in again

[image: console screenshot after]

We can find the python process has been stopped.

PS: the system is Cent OS 7.0.

Comment: Your question is extremely vague. It's not clear what `wget` has to do with anything. It first appears in your question when you mention that it's not running. It's not clear exactly what `ps` command line you used or how you determined what did or didn't appear in it.

Comment: What is your OS ? FreeBSD, Linux, other unix, or windows ?

Comment: The operation system on the remote cluster is Linux CentOs.

Answer (score 5):

You should use

```
ps ax | grep ProcessName
```

because, according to [the Manual](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ps):

> **a**
>
> Lift the BSD-style "only yourself" restriction, which is imposed upon the set of all processes when some BSD-style (without "-") options are used or when the ps personality setting is BSD-like. The set of processes selected in this manner is in addition to the set of processes selected by other means. An alternate description is that this option causes ps to list all processes with a terminal (tty), or to list all processes when used together with the x option.
>
> **x**
>
> Lift the BSD-style "must have a tty" restriction, which is imposed upon the set of all processes when some BSD-style (without "-") options are used or when the ps personality setting is BSD-like. The set of processes selected in this manner is in addition to the set of processes selected by other means. An alternate description is that this option causes ps to list all processes owned by you (same EUID as ps), or to list all processes when used together with the a option.